# Is virtualenv referencing a global library?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, nose

I have a Python script that uses the `nose` library to set some custom options before running my tests. My project is in a **virtualenv** that uses Python *2.5*. My global Python version was recently upgraded to *2.7*, but because I'm using a virtualenv, I should be shielded. However, the last few lines look like they're referencing a non-local version of `nosegae`.

Where is **build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nosegae.py** located? It looks local, but that relative path does not exist.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/run_nosetests.py", line 70, in <module>
    nose.run(argv=nose_opts)
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/core.py", line 282, in run
    return TestProgram(*arg, **kw).success
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/core.py", line 117, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/unittest.py", line 767, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/core.py", line 134, in parseArgs
    self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/config.py", line 324, in configure
    self.plugins.begin()
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 93, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/jazzy_jack/lib/python2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.3-py2.5.egg/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 161, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nosegae.py", line 129, in begin
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nosegae.py", line 153, in _install_hook
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: How about something like: ```sudo find /|grep 'nosegae.py'```? Assuming you're using something unixish by your paths... That'll list all locations of that file.

Comment: Also after: ```virtualenv test; cd test; . bin/activate; pip install nosegae nose; find . |grep nosegae```, the only location of nosegae.py is ```./lib/python2.7/site-packages/nosegae.py```. So first, how did you install nosegae? And second, did you remember to run ```. bin/activate```?

Comment: you can not run appengine under virtualenv.  Any library used by appengine must be copied into the project.

Comment: virtualenv is useful though for resolving dependencies etc and defining what libs you need to include in your project.

Comment: Thank you, both. I grepped for 'nosegae.py' and got no results. I then grepped for 'bdist.linux-x86_64' and got 3 folders, all of which were empty. Not one of them contained 'nosegae.py' or any subfolders. Would this 'build' folder be created on-the-fly?